# Метод внутри метода в языке C#

Tags: c#, методы, теория

Изучаем программирование в ВУЗе, язык C#. Когда мы писали код на первых нескольких занятиях, я написал по старой привычке метод внутри метода:

```
public static void Main() { static void Example() { } }
```

Препод сказал, что так не делается(нельзя писать метод внутри метода), на логичный вопрос "почему?" ответа более развёрнутого, чем "так не принято" я не услышал. Поэтому прошу у Вас, дорогие IT-шники, хоть какого-то более или менее понятного объяснения, почему так делать не нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: "я написал по старой привычке" - и что, скомпилировалось?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вижу, ввёл всех в некоторое заблуждение. Вопрос КОНКРЕТНО следующий: почему в C# не принято писать метод внутри метода?

Comment: ...........а зачем?))

Comment: "P.S.S.S Не спрашивайте, зачем, я просто хочу понять, почему так не принято" --- нет, так это не работает. Если вы спрашиваете. значит вы хотите так сделать. Тогда вы должны бы сказать - какова острая необходимость так делать? В чём профит? и т.д. в ином случае, если вы не можете ответить на этот вопрос, то нет смысла отвечать, зачем так делать не стОит)) Потому что это просто хотелка-вертелка без оснований))

Comment: Ну, хорошо. У меня был метод внутри метода Main, пусть он называется Example. По ходу работы метода Main мы приходили к тому, что в Example что-то передавалось и метод выполнялся. Препод заметил, что в таком случае метод в методе писать не вариант, и что нужно выносить такие методы за пределы главного метода Main. Я понимаю, что это упрощает чтение кода, но есть ли ещё какие-то причины для этого? То есть я себя должен сознательно ограничить, потому что это правило хорошего тона?

Comment: Потому что C# - это строгая типизация, ООП, а также ряд правил по типу SOLID, которые, наоборот, вам говорят "каждый объект должен отвечать за одну конкретную задачу", а ваши методы в методах - это код спагетти, где вы плюете на все правила, запихивая в один класс, метод, кучу лишней логики, которая попросту не должна там быть. Лучше отвыкайте от этой привычки, старайтесь все держать в своих методах, классах, а также подумайте про замену того или иного участка кода без переписывания всего проекта целиком (привет наследование, интерфрейсы).

Comment: Спасибо, EvgeniyZ, это именно тот ответ, который я хотел услышать. Если объясните как, то я ваш ответ помечу как ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: В текущем виде код не компилируется.

Comment: "Не принято" "C# это ООП" и прочее - это дело привычки. У локальных функций есть вполне конкретные области применения, в которых они удобнее/проще/эффективнее чем лямбды или просто отдельные методы, и конкретные кейсы очень подробно разобраны в https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions. Локальные именованные функции - это классика ФП, используйте их при необходимости. Ну а преподу сдайте с отдельным методом - это его проблемы :)

Comment: локальные функции могут менять переменные в своих родительских функциях (что сильно затрудняет их понимание). им можно вобще не передавать аргументы. пишите обычными функциями и не создавайте проблем себе и тем, кто захочет разобраться в вашем коде. вы должны понимать, что никаких локальных функций нет, [они преобразуются компилятором в обычные](https://habr.com/ru/post/346174/)

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать [локальные функции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) или нет, это вопрос стиля, если не идет речь о лямбдах и захвате переменных (т.е. когда мы выбираем между локальной функцией и обычным приватным статическим методом). Кому-то они покажутся полезными, так как позволяют сузить видимость функции и приблизить ее определение к месту использования, а кому-то нет, из-за дополнительной вложенности или из-за возможности случайно привнести захват переменных при рефакторинге. Как и любое соглашение о стиле, оно всегда субъективно, и определяется тем, кто ведет проект. Общепринятых рекомендаций использовать или не использовать локальные функции мне пока неизвестно.  Эта возможность языка слишком новая, и все еще не оценили, насколько они полезны и в каких случаях. Каждый устанавливает свои локальные правила, или просто лепит как попало. Но локальные функции несомненно уже используются в реальных проектах, например [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/d4e8ed5bc68dd4d3bb374ee73fdaf5d80ab6e2e3/src/Features/Core/Portable/EditAndContinue/AbstractEditAndContinueAnalyzer.cs#L3177) в коде от Microsoft (компонент отладчика C# в Visual Studio).

Так что, если преподаватель сказал не использовать локальные функции, этому стоит следовать. Но, если ответить буквально, то нет такого правила, что в C# нельзя писать метод внутри метода. Иногда можно.